# Laravel 8 - use route parameter inside the view

Tags: php, laravel

Taking the following code as an example, how can I use the `param` paramenter inside the `index` view?

```
Route::get('foo/{param}', [FooController::class, 'index']);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you `index` method of the controller take a parameter, `$param`, and pass it to your view:

```
public function index($param)
{
    return view('index', ['param' => $param]);
}
```

Then in the Blade view:

```
{{ $param }}
```

Or, you could get the route parameter from the request directly in the view if needed:

```
{{ request()->route('param') }}
```